# How to iterate multiple text files in HDFS in Spark-Scala using a loop?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm working in a cluster. I need to run the same spark operation for each text file contained in HDFS. But I want to do that without submitting spark job shell-command for each file from shell command line, because the number of files is 90.
How can I do that?

My code for one file is structured as follow:

```
object SparkGraphGen{
def main(args: Array[String]){
      val conf = new SparkConf()
                .setMaster("yarn")
                .setAppName("dataset")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
      val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
      import sqlContext.implicits._
      val peopleRDD = sc.textFile("file1.csv")
      ...
      do stuff
      ...
      sc.stop()
      }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update:**

1. how about `foreach` loop:

   ```
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
   //val files = new File("Data\\files\\").listFiles.map(_.getAbsolutePath).toList 
   val files = new File("Data\\files\\").listFiles.map(_.getName).toList           
   files.foreach { file =>  
       //val lines = sc.textFile(file)
       val lines = sc.textFile("Data\\files\\" + file)
       println("total lines in file " + file + "  " + lines.count())   
       //do more stuf... for each file
       lines.saveAsTextFile("Data\\output\\" + file + "_output")
           }   
   sc.stop()
   ```

   output:

   ```
   total lines in file C:\Users\rpatel\workspaces\Spark\Data\files\file1.txt  4
   total lines in file C:\Users\rpatel\workspaces\Spark\Data\files\file2.txt  4
   ```

---

2. you can also write same for loop in shell-script

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   for file in $(hadoop fs -ls /hdfs/path/to/files/|awk -F '|' '{print $NF}')
   do
     #run spark for each file
     spark-submit <options> $file /path/output/$file
   done
   ```

or process all files in one shot....

you can put all files in one directory and pass only full directory path to spark context, spark will process all files in that directory:

```
val peopleRDD = sc.textFile("/path/to/csv_files/")
```

you can also combine RDDs like:

```
    val file1RDD = sc.textFile("file1.csv") 
    val file2RDD = sc.textFile("file2.csv")
    val allFileRDD = file1RDD ++ file2RDD // ++ nRDD
```

but with 90 files, I would put all files in one directory and use directory path to process all in one job...
[image: Test]

Comment: That's not the point, because I need an output file separately from the others. Not only one file for the whole dataset. E.g. file1->outputFile1Directory, file2->outputFile2Directory etc.

Comment: see update - further you can pass input directory path as an argument,